# SwiftUI MVVM: Notify ViewModel when a Service class delegate finishes

Tags: swiftui, mvvm

I have a View, ViewModel (lives in View) and a service class NetworkService (lives in ViewModel). The dependency injection uses Factory, but that's besides the point.

NetworkService performs networking and conforms to URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate, and URLSessionDownloadDelegate.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @InjectedObject(\.contentViewModel) var viewModel
    // ...
}
class ContentViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Injected(\.networkService) var networkService
    // ...
}

class NetworkService: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    // ...
}
extension NetworkService: URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    // ...
}
```

When the delegate returns `didFinishDownloadingTo`, I want the ViewModel to notice this and update the View.

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("Download complete.")
    // ... 
    // tell the parent ViewModel to update UI
  }
```

Right now, I am using `.onChange` in View. This listens to changes to a variable inside NetworkService, and then tells ViewModel to do something.

```
.onChange(of: viewModel.networkService.finishedDownloading) { newValue in
    viewModel.doSomethingAfterDownload()
}
```

This works. But I'm not happy with it because it makes View directly involved in dataflow between ViewModel and its service class.

What is the best way to notify ViewModel about `didFinishDownloadingTo` in the service class, without getting the View involved?

Comment: The `ContentViewModel` already knows about `networkService`, right? Why no just use `Combine` _inside_ `ContentViewModel` to watch `finishedDownloading`?

Comment: Yes, `ContentViewModel` knows about (and owns) `NetworkService`. How would I use Combine to achieve this?

Comment: Have you used Combine before?

Comment: A little, but I don't have a thorough understanding of it. I'm using Combine to listen to updates in NetworkService like: `var anyCancellableNetworkService: AnyCancellable? = nil`, then `override init() { super.init()` and `anyCancellableNetworkService = networkService.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] (_) in Task { @MainActor [weak self] in self?.objectWillChange.send() } }`. That way, I can read `@Published vars` in NetworkService. But not sure how to make `ViewModel` react to delegate trigger of `NetworkService`

Comment: Great. You can try a similar thing with networkService.$finishedDownloading

Comment: You mean to create a var in `NetworkService` called `finishedDownloading`, then somehow have a binding to that var in parent `ViewModel`? Not sure how to create that binding.

Comment: According to your onChange, you already have a property called finishedDownloading. If you need more specific advice, consider including a [mre]

Comment: yes, the current approach is to update `var finishedDownloading: UUID` and that way trigger `onChange` in the View. Not sure how to do that inside `ViewModel`.

Comment: Make it `@Published` and then use the code I suggested.